Terraform import for snowflake resources
I'm new to terraform. Trying to import a existing snowflake resource to the terraform statefile.The structure of the repo is like below.

We are using Snowflake(snowflake-labs) provider for terraform.
Following the module approach. We define the resource in the other repo, to which we refer in the module below (in the source)


module "tags" {
  for_each = { for tag in var.tags : tag.tag_name => tag }
  source   = "git::https://github.com/terraform.git//modules/snowflake/snowflake_tag?ref=main"

  tag_name       = each.value.tag_name
  database_name  = each.value.database_name
  schema_name    = each.value.schema_name
  allowed_values = each.value.allowed_values
  comment        = each.value.comment

  depends_on = [module.ed_governance_database, module.ed_governance_schema]
}


Then we define the actual resources in the config file in list
 tags = [
  {
    tag_name       = "TAG_COST_CENTERR"
    database_name  = "ED_GOVERNANCE_2"
    schema_name    = "ED_GOV"
    allowed_values = ["BO","FINANCE","MARKETING","SALES"]
    comment        = "This is the first tag"
  },
  {
    tag_name       = "TEST_TAG"
    database_name  = "ED_GOVERNANCE_2"
    schema_name    = "ED_GOV"
    allowed_values = []
    comment        = ""
  }
]

So far, for the new resources, managed by terraform it works fine. But I have a scenario, where I want to import the existing resources to be managed by terraform. I tried below, but which is not working.
Added a step in the github workflow, before the terraform plan
- name: Check config
        run: |
          if [ "${{ inputs.backend_config }}" == "ed_governance_prd/backend.tfvars" ]; then
            echo "TRUE"
            export TF_LOG=DEBUG
            terraform import 'module.tags["TEST_TAG"].snowflake_tag.tag' 'ED_GOVERNANCE_2|ED_GOV|TEST_TAG'
          fi

but this is throwing the eror, even I defined the test_tag resource in the above list configuration.
error
│ Error: Configuration for import target does not exist
│ 
│ The configuration for the given import
│ module.tags["TEST_TAG"].snowflake_tag.tag does not exist. All target
│ instances must have an associated configuration to be imported.

